# How to filter (Azure) Collection of Edm.String by count or equility?

Tags: database, azure, indexing, filter, odata

I have models in the index (Azure), like:

```
[
  { list: ['1', '2', '3'] },
  { list: ['1', '3'] },
  { list: ['5', '5', '5'] },
  { list: ['1'] }
]
```

I need to find data where this property (list) has only one exact item '1' using queries (filter), how to make it?

My variants were to use queries:

1. Use `$filter=list/any(item: item eq '1') and list/$count eq 1`, but it seems like there is no such a thing, as count of the items in the collection.
2. Use `$filter=list/all(item: item eq '1')` just to be sure all items are the same (for me it's a tradeoff and I can use it), but `eq` is not allowed inside `all`.
3. Use wildcard patterns `$filter=list/all(item: not search.ismatch('<inversed ignore pattern>', item, 'full', 'all'))`, but `search.ismatch` is not supported inside lambda expressions

How to make it?